# How to display an organized category using groupby in an array angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I want to show tiles organised by their category. 
in the categories I want to show Category_title and Category_intro at the top
and show the the title and description below.

**App.component.html:**

---

This is my html

```
<div class="tools-category" *ngFor="let tool of tools | groupBy:'categories.Category_title' | pairs ">
  <h3>{{tool[0]}}</h3>
  <div class="tools-by-cat">
    <div *ngFor="let val of tool[1]" class="tool-item">
        <h2>{{val.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{val.desc}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

This is my ts component

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {
  tools = [
  {
     id: 0,
     title: 'Title 0',
     desc: 'Description',
     categories: [
       {
          "Category_title": "My Category Title 1",
          "Category_intro": "My Category intro 1",
       }, 
       {
          "Category_title": "My Category Title 2",
          "Category_intro": "My Category intro 2",
       }
         ],
  },
  {
     id: 1,
     title: 'Title 1',
     desc:'Description',
     categories: [
       {
          "Category_title": "My Category Title",
          "Category_intro": "My Category intro 
       },
       {
          "Category_title": "My Category Title 2",
          "Category_intro": "My Category intro 2", 
       }
         ],
   },
   {
      id: 2,title: 'Title 2',
      desc: 'Description',
      cat: 'Category 2',
      categories: [
        {
           "Category_title": "My Category Title",
           "Category_intro": "My Category intro 1",
        },
        {
           "Category_title": "My Category Title 2",
           "Category_intro": "My Category intro 2",
        }
          ],
    },
    {
       id: 3,title: 'Title 3',
       desc: 'Description',
       categories: [
         {
            "Category_title": "My Category Title",
            "Category_intro": "My Category intro 1",
         },
         {
             "Category_title": "My Category Title 2",
             "Category_intro": "My Category intro 2",
         }
           ],
      },
      {
         id: 4,
         title: 'Title 4',
         desc: 'Description',
         categories: [
           {
              "Category_title": "My Category Title",
              "Category_intro": "My Category intro 1",
           },
           {
              "Category_title": "My Category Title 2",
              "Category_intro": "My Category intro 2",
           }
   ],
 }]
```

}

this is the view:
[This is the error view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxCtg.png)

[I want this to display:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERiZV.png)

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Each tool here seems to have multiple categories, in what order do you want to sort this by? 

If you could provide some examples, it would help when answering your question.

Comment: Hi I want to sort the categories where inside of categories I want to display Category_title and Category_intro using *ngFor="let tool of tools | groupBy:'categories.Category_title' | pairs " in my app.component.html I've got [object Object],[object Object] value.

Comment: Code format and screenshot  are updated